# Rails で複数の中間テーブルの作成方法がわからない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

## 前提

現在以下のようなテーブルで多対多の関係を持たせたいと考えています。
フレームワークは Ruby on Rails、DBは PostgreSQL です。

[image: 多対多の関係図]

- 曲は複数の作曲者、作詞者、編曲者をもつ
- アーティストは複数の曲を持つ

ような関係です。

---

そこで、有識者の方から、中間テーブルをそれぞれに用意して以下のようにすればいいのではと助言していただきました。

[image: 中間テーブル]

## 状況

助言の意図は理解できたつもりだったのですが、いまいちコーディングの仕方が分かりません。

最終的には、

- アーティストの曲
- 曲の作曲者
- 曲の作詞者

という風にデータを参照できればと思っています。

## 質問

- このようなリレーションでのモデルのカラムの書き方。
- モデル(.rb)での`has_many`や`belongs_to`の書き方。
- もしあれば、中間テーブルを使わないようなその他のアイディア。

以上３点についてお答えしていただければと思います。
拙い文章でもうしわけありません。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

動かしたわけではないので参考程度にお願いします。
ArtistとSongモデルはすでにあるという前提です。また、一般的なRailsモデルとしてidが主キーという理解で書いています

> このようなリレーションでのモデルのカラムの書き方。

モデルとマイグレーション生成

```
$ rails g model ComposerSong
$ rails g model LyricistSong
$ rails g model ArrangerSong
```

各カラムの記述

```
# db/migrates/xxxx_create_composer_songs.rb
class CreateComposerSongs < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :composer_songs do |t|
        t.references :composer, foreign_key: { to_table: :artists }
        t.references :song, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end

# db/migrates/xxxx_create_lyricist_songs.rb
class CreateLyricistSongs < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :lyricist_songs do |t|
        t.references :lyricist, foreign_key: { to_table: :artists }
        t.references :song, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end

# db/migrates/xxxx_create_arranger_songs.rb
class CreateArrangerSongs < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :arranger_songs do |t|
        t.references :arranger, foreign_key: { to_table: :artists }
        t.references :song, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

> モデル(.rb)でのhas_manyやbelongs_toの書き方。

ArtistとSongモデルはcomposer, lyricist, arrangerという中間テーブルが3つありそれぞれにアクセスできる必要があります。このため、 `has_many :through` の部分では中間テーブル名に_songsまたは_artistsをつけてアクセスする命名にしています。ここは好きに変更してください

SongやArtistの削除時の中間テーブルの振る舞いは書いていないので注意してください。

```
# app/model/composer_song.rb
class ComposerSong < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :composer, class_name: "Artist", foreign_key: "artist_id"
    belongs_to :song
end

# app/model/lyricist_song.rb
class LyricistSong < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :lyricist, class_name: "Artist", foreign_key: "artist_id"
    belongs_to :song
end

# app/model/arranger_song.rb
class ArrangerSong < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :arranger, class_name: "Artist", foreign_key: "artist_id"
    belongs_to :song
end


# app/model/artist.rb
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :composer_songs
    has_many :composer_song_songs, through: :composer_songs

    has_many :lyricist_songs
    has_many :lyricist_song_songs, through: :lyricist_songs

    has_many :arranger_songs
    has_many :arranger_song_songs, through: :arranger_songs
end

# app/model/song.rb
class Song < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :composer_songs
    has_many :composer_song_artists, through: :composer_songs

    has_many :lyricist_songs
    has_many :lyricist_song_artists, through: :lyricist_songs

    has_many :arranger_songs
    has_many :arranger_song_artists, through: :arranger_songs
end
```

> もしあれば、中間テーブルを使わないようなその他のアイディア。

私のほうでは特に良い実装は思いつきません

Comment: ありがとうございました。

多対多のコントローラの作り方が分からなくなったので、それは別質問で建てようと思います。

よろしければ、力をお貸しください。